# Set Ultimaker Cura 5.1 default save name

Tags: ultimaker-cura

I use SD cards to print on a Printrbot Simple Metal, and the Simple will automatically print the file named `auto0.g`. The issue here is that Cura, by default, saves files as something like `PS-part.gcode`. So, is there a way to make it save under the name `auto0.g` by default?

Cura Version: 5.1

Answer (score 1):

Cura by default prefixes the saved g-code with the machine name, I take it yours is named Printrbot Simple Metal or something similar, so Cura assigns it the "PS-" prefix.

To disable this, you can click on 'Preferences' in Menu Bar on the top left of the Window, and go to `Preferences > General > Opening and Saving Files` and deselect the option "Add machine prefix to job name."

You can also save your 3D model files as auto0.g, and when Cura loads, slices, and then saves the G-Code file, it will be named auto0.g.

Beyond that, there's the little Pen/Paper icon in the bottom left, just above the perspective buttons (cubes) to rename the file before saving it. AFAIK, there is no way to save the G-Code automatically with a different name than the file/model you loaded into it.

Comment: The problem seems to be that there is no way to change the save extension, and it always saves with a `.gcode` extension, which I have to change.

Comment: I forgot about the extension itself, I don't think there's a way to save files as a .g from Cura. Sorry about that.